# How to add Jquery code snippet in the HTML editor for footer_cms_content

Tags: magento2, javascript, frontend, jquery

When I place this code :-

```
$(".social-icons").after('<span id="siteseal" style="style="cursor: hand;"></span>');
$.getScript("https://seal.godaddy.com/getSeal?sealID=beP8DWYRCbG8YIK0Chdr8BKQQsmmOG3jEF1rddbw106hSZicW0fWglZgVTRQ",function(){"";
});
```

at the end of the HTML for footer_cms_content, it just displays the the code itself instead of the Godaddy Trust Seal. Is it possible to place it in this cms block for footer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am only for you suggest. may be help you

Magento 2 jquery or javascript not add in cms block SO you create the simple the .phtml file and call the your footer cms block like :-

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Vendor_Module::myfiles/myfile.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Thanks Mohit. This is the right way to do it given the fact that the code includes jquery.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a static block with your code and then call the static block via `/app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

```
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="godaddy.seal" before="-">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_code_name</argument>
    </arguments>                    
</block>
```

`<move element="godaddy.seal" destination="footer_cms_content" before="-"/>`

Comment: thanks for the solution. I shall keep this in mind for one of the upcoming projects.